# How to count comparison and recursive function call?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a program that gives Fibonacci series using recursive method. Now I want to count comparison and recursive function call. Could anyone explain me the way to count comparison and recursive function call?

```
public class FibonacciRecursive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        long i;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%19d", fibRecursive(i));
            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        if ((i - 1) % 4 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static long fibRecursive(long n)
    {
        if (n <= 2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return fibRecursive(n - 2) + fibRecursive(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add two counters and increment them after comparisons and `fibRecursive()` calls.

```
public class FibonacciRecursive {
private static long comparisons = 0;
private static long recursionCalls = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    long n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
    long i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%19d", fibRecursive(i));
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    if ((i - 1) % 4 != 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(comparisons);
    System.out.println(recursionCalls);
}

private static long fibRecursive(long n) {
    comparisons++;
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        recursionCalls += 2;
        return fibRecursive(n - 2) + fibRecursive(n - 1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @f1sh now it compiles for sure.

Comment: @f1sh also recursionCalls supposed to be incremented by 2, right?

Comment: should not recursionCalls and comparison be equal for this method?

Comment: @K.Ji you have 1 condition and 2 method calls